# Potassium bicarbonate or sodium bicarbonate

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, home-experiment

How would I go about determining whether a sample of an unknown substance is either potassium bicarbonate or sodium bicarbonate (given that the sample is one or the other)?

Comment: Related: [How can I identify whether a substance is KOH or NaOH?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/14923/7951)

Comment: Easiest: flame test - yellow for Na, purple for K. However, the Na yellow lines are extremely bright, and if there's any Na contamination, the purple K lines are hard to see without a spectroscope (or diffraction grating).

Comment: @Loong  It's a dupe, same cations to discern.